# Get attribute value based on condition from other attribute in xpath element

Tags: java, xpath, automation

I am trying in my **JAVA** code, to list all the disabled job names. I was trying to create an `xpath` that will list those but I could only get the Never values listed.
My code lists 5 Never values. I have 5 disabled jobs but I want to display the name of those jobs.

**JAVA Code:**

```java
List<WebElement> jobList = driver.
    findElements(By.xpath(
        "//*[contains(@class,'sectionhead expandComponentHolder')]//*[contains(@class,'scheduletime disabled')] "
    )
);

Iterator<WebElement> itr = jobList.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext()) {
    WebElement row = itr.next();
    System.out.println(row.getText());
}
```

**XML:**

```
<tr class = "testclass" >
   <td class = "jobname" data-job-id="jobidtest" data-job-name="jobname" data-job-group="jobgroup"></td>
   <td class = "scheduletime">
       <span class = "scheduletime disabled" title data-toogle="tooltip" data-placemenet="auto left" data-original-title="Job schedule is disabled">
          <i class ="glyphicon-time">…</i>
          <span class = "detail">Never</span>
       </span>
    </td> 
</tr>
```

Comment: Given your xml, what exactly is your desired output?

Comment: So, I have multiple <tr> tags that contain a jobname and a scheduletime. I would like to list the jobname (the value from data-job-name from the first <td>  tag) for all the jobs that are disabled (for which the second <td> tag contains Never text or scheduletime disabled class ) . Hope this is the clear. Thanks.

Comment: " all the jobs that are disabled (for which the second <td> tag contains Never text or scheduletime disabled class )" - do these two always come together, or is it possible that a `class = "scheduletime disabled"` will NOT be followed by `Never` text?

Comment: Those two always come together. All the disabled jobs are marked with Never text next to their names.

Comment: Ok, then; see answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the follwing xpath expression on your xml and see if it works:

```
//*[contains(@class,'sectionhead expandComponentHolder')]//span[contains(@class,'scheduletime disabled')]/../preceding-sibling::td
```

The expression itself, on your xml above should output:

> jobname

Comment: Thanks Jack. The xpath expression will return the jobname of the disabled jobs. However, when running the java code, I have the following error: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "//*[contains(@class,'sectionhead expandComponentHolder')]//span[contains(@class,'scheduletime disabled')]/../preceding-sibling::td/@data-job-name" is: [object Attr]. It should be an element.

Comment: The Java Block code is this one :   
        List<WebElement> jobList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//[contains(@class,'sectionhead expandComponentHolder')]//span[contains(@class,'scheduletime disabled')]/../preceding-sibling::td/@data-job-name"));
        
        Iterator<WebElement> itr = jobList.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()) {
            WebElement row = itr.next();
            System.out.println(row.getText());
        }

Comment: @MihaelaIlie - I see; try removing the attribute; see edited expression above. You may need to modify your java code to look for the attribute name (`data-job-name`) instead of the text of that `td`.

Comment: @MihaelaIlie - Glad it worked for you! If you're done, just accept the answer, please.